# C# notepad alike file read

Tags: c#

I have a file. When I open it in Notepad I see charachters in a single line. However, if I open that file in any other application like [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad) or [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++). I can see irregular line breaks between charachters and they appear in multiple lines. These line breaks also appears if I do `reader.Readline()`. How can I perform Notepad like line read in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for second answer from me, but I just realised that you could use peek to get next character and check if current and next are \r\n, like so:

```
var path = "c:/test.txt";

File.WriteAllText(path, "a\nb\r\nc");

using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    var lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    string line;
    char currentChar;
    int nextChar;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        currentChar = (char)reader.Read();
        nextChar = reader.Peek();

        if (!(currentChar == '\r' && nextChar == '\n'))
        {
            lineBuilder.Append(currentChar);
        }

        if((currentChar == '\r' && nextChar == '\n') || nextChar == -1)
        {
            line = lineBuilder.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(line);

            lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            reader.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Such differences are usually because of ambiguity over which encoding the file uses. If you want the file top parse correctly, you'll need to use the right encoding. What characters are causing problems? Also - if the bytes aren't legal in the encoding used, all bets are off ;-p

You can specify the encoding when creating (for example) a `StreamReader` over the file:

```
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

---

With the base-64 posted, the problem is the `\r` in the middle of the line. To read this as a basic string, you could use:

```
 byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
 string txt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

or just:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText("foo.txt");
```

However, you'll always have difficulty displaying this. You can now `Split` on your **chosen** line ending (crlf presumably). `StreamReader` is splitting on anything that looks *like* a line ending.

```
string[] lines = s.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: I tried all type of encoding set for this file, each one is breaking the line in two, Its only notepad where I see it as single line, Wish I could attach file here.

Comment: Indeed. It sounds like something "interesting" in the underlying bytes of the file. Is it big? You could post the hex/base-64 representation...

Comment: MjAwOTAzMDR8RVVST3x8MDAwMDJ8RkZGRnwgfEF8U3w3MTB8TUxJICAgfCB8fA0gIHwgLjAwMDAwfCAuMDAwMDB8LjAwMDAwfDIwMDkwMzA0IDA4OjMxOjIzOjYxQU18IHwgfCB8IHwgICAgfHwgICAgfCB8LjAwfCAgIA==

Comment: If I understood Brijesh he would like using \r\n sequence for line termination. Though his file has \n symbols at the end of each line .Net still interpreters them as separate lines. Notepad/Wordpad dilemma is because of the same reason. Notepad doesn't interpreter \n while Wordpad does

Comment: MjAwOTAzMDR8RVVST3x8MDAwMDJ8RkZGRnwgfEF8U3w3MTB8TUxJICAgfCB8fA0gIHwgLjAwMDAwfCAuMDAwMDB8LjAwMDAwfDIwMDkwMzA0IDA4OjMxOjIzOjYxQU18IHwgfCB8IHwgICAgfHwgICAgfCB8LjAwfCAgIA==

Comment: File.ReadAllText (path, Encoding.UTF8)

Comment: Spot on, this will solve this issue but only problem will be size of file which is always in gigabytes opening it with ReadAll might cause application to crash

Comment: In that case, you'll have to do your own line parsing... read blocks of data hunting for \r\n - and append (perhaps StringBuilder) until then. Not trivial, I'm afraid, especially with variable length encodings. I don't have an easy answer...

Answer (score 0):

If this is not that critical you could just load all text and split it into lines using a regular expression or something,

```
var path = "c:/test.txt";

File.AppendAllText(path, "lala\nlala\nlalal");
var text = File.ReadAllText(path);

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Split(text, Environment.NewLine).Length);
```

Comment: File size are in gigs so cant do ReadAllText

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\text.txt");
```

To extract all lines in one shot